# $.ajax JSON not passing values on complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm having an annoying issue, on complete i get **undefined** when trying to make simple url validation. success working fine.

i get a valid json response:

```
{"error":"some error"}
```

and this is my jQuery

```
$("#myform").submit(function(){
            dataString = $("#myform").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type:       "GET",
                url:        "myform.php",
                data:       $.URLDecode(dataString), //fixing url problem
                dataType:   "json",
                beforeSend: function(){ 
                        $('#search').append('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />'); //loader
                        $('.error').remove(); //removes every submit
                    }, 
                success:    function(data){
                                    $('<span class="error">' + data.error + '</span>').appendTo($('#search'));

                            },
                complete:   function(data){ 
                                $('#search img').fadeOut(); //removes loader
                                    alert(data.error);

                }

            });
            return false;  //force ajax submit
        });
```

Any hint please?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the docs:

> complete(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus)
>
> A function to be called when the
>   request finishes (after success and
>   error callbacks are executed). The
>   function gets passed two arguments:
>   The XMLHttpRequest object and a string
>   describing the status of the request.
>   This is an Ajax Event.

Data is not a return value from your method.

If you're using firebug, use console.log(XMLHttpRequest) and you'll see what it includes.

You can also do this (quick - using eval here - not recommended.)

```
var err = eval("(" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ")");
alert(err.Message);
```

Comment: I see, basically i don't really want to alert data.error, that was just an example. but i need json values to be passed to the complete function. well i'll try to work this around, thanks.

Comment: Like others have said, the data is not available here. Use .success instead.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), the complete event doesn't hold your json response.

Why do you need to define the complete handler and the success handler? Just define success.

Answer (score -2):

maybe $.URLDecode() returns not JSON key/value structure

Answer (score -2):

I think you want URLEncode not URLDecode? Either way I'd recommend [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) for debugging issues like this - it'll show you exactly what's being sent to/from the server.